# Initialization of sub-classes in main constructors - body of main constructor versus sub-class constructor body

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I have legacy code that has a class that contains many other sub-classes as data members.  Most of these read in various inputs into data members in the sub-classes.  It looks something like this:

```
MainClass::MainClass(std::string &directory, LogClass &logClass, int mode1, int mode2, int mode3,) : 
    logClass(logClass),                                                                                           
    subClass1(directory, logClass, mode1),                                                  
    subClass2(directory, logClass),                                                                                                                                      
    subClass3(logClass, subClass1, subClass2, mode1, mode2),
    subClass4(logClass, subClass1, subClass2, subClass3, mode1, mode2, mode3),
{
    if(mode2 == 0)                         
    {
        subClass3.init();
    }
    subClass4.init();
}
```

In some of the subClasses, initialization occurs in the body of their constructors.  At other times, the initialization of important data members occurs in the body of the mainClass, as seen the case of subClass3 and subClass4.

I am altering this code to contain other subClasses which handle transformations of the previously read in data.  Some of these new classes require initialization of other classes before they can be constructed.  For instance, if I add subClass5, it might require subClass4.init() to have been run.  But as can be seen in the code, subClass4.init() isn't run til the body of the constructor.

What is a good policy here to follow moving forward?  Should I pull out all of the initializations from the subClass constructors into their own init() functions and order them properly in the main class constructor?  Or should I move all of the initializations into the subClass constructors and tray and order them properly?

I'm trying to figure out the most proper code design for this problem.

Comment: If the example mirrors the legacy code, I would consider to refactor it. Whenever I see "mode" parameters, I have the feeling that it should be done by sub-classing, or - preferably - by using strategy or a similar pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It depends from the *semantic* of the `init()` functions. What do they do? And what do their constructors do? Why two distinct functions (constructor and `init`) for initialization?

In a lot of code I've seen, usually `init`s functions are due mainly to their implementer's sloppery. What they do **belongs** to the constructor, from the C++ perspective.

On the other hand, if `init()`s functions are used to perform something that is *semantically* disjoint from object construction (e.g. starting a timer, triggering some event, ...), maybe it is good they are disjoint from the constructor. In this case, I would change their name, though.

Answer (score 0):

Methods like `init()` helps in delegating initialization process to a later time and thus allows quick startup because the constructors don't have to spend much time doing `init()`. This is especially true if those `init` methods are performing costly operations as in using intensive CPU cycles or acquiring costly resources.

On the other hand, if you impose such protocol, then anyone who is adding a `subClassX` must ensure proper initialization by calling subclass constructor and followed by invoking `init` on those subclasses.

The choice is entirely yours as both approaches has got some pros and cons. If you find more pros than cons go for it!

P.S. Of course this assumes that constructors are doing enough to get subclass instances into minimal usable state.

Comment: If you need to call init before you can use the object, it will create an invalid object where invariants do not hold. For performance reason, you could either instantiate the object when needed and let the constructor run then, or use a (unique_)pointer as member and create it lazily.

Comment: What is a *minimal usable state*? If the initialization of an object is time consuming, you may want to perform it on another thread, but Resource Acquisition Is Initialization...

Comment: I see your unique pointer approach and lazy initialization, but if constructors can get things going on startup, delegating a costly `init` is often widely used idea. For ex: GUI objects hungry at acquiring some bitmaps. This can be effectively delegated to a later point in time.

Comment: @Arun I think we have some misunderstanding, at least from my side. When a see an init method, I usually interpret it as "before I can do anything with the object, I have to call init". This is what I would prevent. In your GUI example, the object is perfectly valid and can be used, e.g. to load bitmaps. Maybe a different for init, e.g. loadVisuals() would be better.

Comment: @Paolo M, By  _minimal usable state_, I mean just providing enough identity to those objects for other subsystem to identify them, but, perhaps  usable only after _init_ ing them

Comment: In this case, an `init` function represents a design flaw, imho.

Comment: @Arun "Minimal usable state" should mean "establish the invariants". There is no smaller usable state because the invariants are the conditions that need to hold when a (public) method gets executed. Relying on an init-call is at least bad-practice, I would say it is ill-formed code.

Comment: @Jens, agree init is just an abstract name, loadVisuals would be better, I've seen atleast two production level custom framework doing things this way and it perfectly fits into this paradigm. Some manager class takes the responsiblity of initing subobjects only when required. May be, we do not completely see each other's point, it is difficult to explain the structure and scope of such frameworks in a few little words!

Answer (score 0):

The constructor should always establish the invariants of the class, nothing more or less. I would strongly argue that a class that is in an invalid state after construction and has to be initialized with an `init()` call is ill-formed.

For testing purposes, I would consider moving the construction of the sub-parts out of the class and supply them to the constructor, or supply a factory for each of them. This enables you to create mocks for the sub-parts and is very helpful for unit testing.